# how to create the grafana templating variables for dynamically switching to required labels

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev1SC.png)I have created a dashboard for the DCGM metrics to see the notebooks gpu usage and all. For that I have the following query

```bash
sum(DCGM_FI_DEV_FB_TOTAL) by (exported_pod) 
* on (exported_pod) group_left() 
label_replace(
  kube_pod_labels{label_notebook_name="gen-ai-solutions"},
  "exported_pod", "$1", 
  "pod", "(.*)")
```

so this will give me the total frame buffer memory available for the specific notebook by using the label (label_notebook_name="gen-ai-solutions"). So I have so many number of notebooks with different label keys and values.

So, what I have been trying is creating the dashboard variables. For that I have created two drop downs for the dashboards with names `label_key` and `label_value`.

```
Variable    Definition  
label_key   label_values(kube_pod_labels , __name__)        
label_value label_values(kube_pod_labels{label_key="$label_key"}, label_value)
```

so I added like this, but I am not able to see the related label keys and values in the dropdown. It's showing none.

I am using Grafana 7.5.8 app version and data source is Prometheus.

Comment: Query `label_values(kube_pod_labels , __name__)` will return you only `kube_pod_labels` as a result, because `__name__` label in Prometheus corresponds to name of the metric. Can you explain (preferably with examples) what you want to achieve and what data you have in the metric `kube_pod_labels`?

Comment: sum(DCGM_FI_DEV_FB_TOTAL) by (exported_pod) 
* on (exported_pod) group_left() 
label_replace(
  kube_pod_labels{label_notebook_name="gen-ai-solutions"},
  "exported_pod", "$1", 
  "pod", "(.*)")          this will give me the  notebook gpu frame buffer usage. so if i want to switch to another notebook i will just change the (label_notebook_name="gen-ai-solutions"). example if i have another notebook with a label of  app1_name="notebook2-us" so, what i will do use i just simply change the label in above query by using this. so for that i need templating. hope you understand my requirement.

Comment: For the `label_key` you should use Label names instead of label values (but I'm not sure if it's supported by Grafana 7, and I don't have that old version at hand to test it).  In version 10 your variable should be configured as `Label names`, `kube_pod_labels` and regex `label_(.+)`. Check if something like this can be done in your version

Comment: yeah. but when we give label names that mean we are manually configuring the labels. thats not our condition right. if we have the templating varaibles i will select in the drop down and my query will look like               
 sum(DCGM_FI_DEV_FB_TOTAL) by (exported_pod) * on (exported_pod) group_left() label_replace( kube_pod_labels{label_$label_key="$label_value"}, "exported_pod", "$1", "pod", "(.*)") so i want that how to get the all the avilable labels in drop down and need to select the appropriate value for them.could you please help me out this. also thanks for the quick response

Comment: can you please,check the updated image on above. thanks